# jQuery Datatables - How to create a "Server-side processing" fiddle?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am trying to answer some questions here in that are related to **server side processing** , but I am unable to create a decent fiddle with it, I managed to create only hard-coded tables.

Can anyone take **[this fiddle](https://plnkr.co/edit/Wm7K4OkcK0X1RQiN1rZL?p=preview)** and modify it to use server side processing from the **data.js** file?

This is how I try to use it:

```
 var table = $('#changeLogTable').DataTable({
            "bLengthChange": false,
            "bPaginate": true,
            "bInfo": false,
            "autoWidth": false, 
            "order": [[0, "desc"]],
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "sAjaxSource": "../data.js"
        });
```

But I keep getting error about json format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is to use this: `"sAjaxSource": "data.js"` instead `"sAjaxSource": "../data.js"`

View [plunker here.](https://plnkr.co/edit/CcQFlJov7QzCcCyUkWs7?p=preview)